# How can I grab all function parameters values list and chain them to a logging class in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, logging, macros

We have a huge set of functions exposed as an external API and we need to trace all argument values in each call. Currently we have a macro that accepts the list of all parameters:

```
 void SomeApiFunction( bool parameter1, const wchar_t* parameter2 )
 {
     LOG_PARAMETERS( parameter1 << parameter2 )
     //function payload
 }
```

The macro expands as follows:

```
 #define LOG_PARAMETERS( x ) GlobalLoggerObject << x;
```

and `GlobalLoggerObject` is of type `class CLogger` that has `operator <<` overloaded for all possible parameter types - something like this:

```
template<class TypeToLog>
CLogger& operator << (const TypeToLog& parameter)
{
   //logging code
   return *this;
}
```

so that we can have a parameters list of any length and thanks to a chain of `<<` they can be all passed into the macro and necessary concrete versions of `operator <<` are instantiated depending on the type of the parameter.

Great except we have to maintain the list of parameters fully synchronous to that of the surrounding function.

Is there some way to just grab all the parameters at once - something like this:

```
TRACE_ALL_PARAMETERS( UNIVERSAL_MAGIC )
```

so that we don't have to list each parameter explicitly?

Comment: I think I didn't understand the question properly, because as I see that should already work : http://www.ideone.com/0Kp87

Comment: Alright, now I did understand it after reading twice. :D... +1 for good question!

Comment: @Nawaz: That code you link to does the same as we currently do - it explicitly lists all parameters.

Comment: @sharptooth: Let me confirm if I understood your question correctly. Right now, the logger uses `<<` as many times to log the parameters, as there are number of parameters. So you want to log all at once using just one `<<`, right?

Comment: @Nawaz: No, I don't care of `<<` or anything else, I just don't want to manually feed them into the macro.

Comment: @Nawaz: I think what he wants is a way that does not require him to update the logging statement each time the signature of the function changes.

Comment: @sharptooth: So how do you want to write the MACRO? Can you write some pseudo-code to further clarify your question?

Comment: @Nawaz: I secretly hoped that there's some Visual C++ specific macro that would for example chain all parameters for me or anything like that.

Comment: @sharptooth: I don't think there is any such macro. Even `__FUNCSIG__` doesn't mention the parameter name.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do it in C/C++, but it can be accomplished with external code generation.

- A programmer, when writing a function, puts `TRACE_ALL_PARAMETERS()` (with empty arguments list) when needed.
- A script parses the source to find all instances of `/^\s*TRACE_ALL_PARAMETERS\(/`, parses out the nearest list of parameter names, and replaces everything in parentheses following `TRACE_ALL_PARAMETERS` with extracted parameter list.

This script can be invoked as a custom build step or as an IDE macro.

That said, it doesn't seem to me a worthwhile investment of time and complication of the code management process. From my personal experience, it is rarely needed to just print all function parameters. Usually one needs to specify custom formatting for some parameters, access some parameters in a special way (e.g. it makes no sense to print a `MyStruct*` as a pointer, usually I'd like to print `p_my_struct->field_1` and `p_my_struct->field_2` instead), etc.

So I'd keep the manual logging, and use an external tool for wholesale tracing if needed. E.g. on Windows, [WinAPIOverride32](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/) can be used, though with additional work to describe functions in the format it understands (I did it once, using [GCC-XML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html) to generate function descriptions).

Answer (score 1):

If this is really a problem, one idea might be to add a runtime check for your unit tests.

As Nawaz mentions in one comment, there is the `__FUNCSIG__` macro, that lists all paremeter types. For example for my main it expands to  `"int __cdecl main(int,char *[])"`.

Now, what you could do is to use this string to do a runtime check of the number (maybe even types) of parameters logged and if you have a mismatch use some mechanism of your test framework to signal that the function's logging is "broken".

As for the problem with not being able to split the parameters being passed to the logging macro: I'd try something like this:

```
#define LOG_WITH_CHECK(ValidationString, Params)                          \
    cout << "Validate [" ValidationString << "] vs. [" << #Params << "]\n"; \
    cout << "Now feed params to logging: {" << Params << "}";               \
/**/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  LOG_WITH_CHECK(__FUNCSIG__, argc << argv[0]);
  ...
```

That is, you also validate the passed parameters as a `<<` separated string.

Comment: Good idea, except I can't detect the number of elements in the list because the list is turned into a chain of `<<` statements after preprocessing and I can't get a hold of it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard confirming way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can add compile-time check for parameters passed to logger.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template<typename F>
void log(F*
    , typename boost::function_traits<F>::arg1_type p1
    )
{ std::cout << p1 << std::endl; }

template<typename F>
void log(F*
    , typename boost::function_traits<F>::arg1_type p1
    , typename boost::function_traits<F>::arg2_type p2
    )
{ std::cout << p1 << p2 << std::endl; }

// ... more overloads

void foo(int x)
{
    log(&foo, x);
}

int main()
{
    foo(42);
}
```

Or, you can avoid doing these overloads deducing boost.fusion type from function type.

Comment: Looks like I have to manually mention the arguments again and that's what I wanted to eliminate.

Comment: @sharptooth yes, but compiler will check their quantity and order.

Answer (score -2):

You could try to use the non-standard **VA_ARGS** macro. Although non-standard, most compilers support it.

A very simple approach would be to 'stringify' all arguments and print that. With a little creativity, I am sure you can come up with something better:

```
#include <iostream>
#define ALLARGS( ... ) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__  << std::endl;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    ALLARGS( "two arguments", 1.0 );
    ALLARGS( "five arguments", 1.0, 1.0, true, 'c' );
}
```